# How to refresh plots when data is changed

Tags: angular, typescript

I am not familiar with front-end development. So this question might be naive or phrased unclearly.

I have a plots container to host variable number of plots. It suppose to refresh every plot when the data was changed. So I made the plot container to subscribe to a data change flag in the data service. But my question is how can I refresh each individual plot (app-plot-bulk-rnaseq-expr) when I detect the data was changed.

html

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let item of this.dataService.exprData | keyvalue">
        <app-plot-bulk-rnaseq-expr [data]=item.value></app-plot-bulk-rnaseq-expr>
    </div>
</div>
```

ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataSharingBulkRNASeqService } from 'src/app/services/data-sharing-bulk-rnaseq.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plot-holder-expr',
  templateUrl: './plot-holder-expr.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plot-holder-expr.component.css']
})
export class PlotHolderExprComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public dataService: DataSharingBulkRNASeqService,
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.exprDataChange.subscribe((value) => {
      this.refresh();
    });
  }

  refresh() {
    **// what to do to refresh each plot**
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**From my point of view it should seems like:**

Html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div *ngFor="let item of myValue | keyvalue">
        <app-plot-bulk-rnaseq-expr [data]=item.value></app-plot-bulk-rnaseq-expr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component class:

```
myValue; <-property of class

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.exprDataChange.subscribe((value) => {
      this.myValue = value;
    });
  }
```